# Dealing with & , 's and space between words

Tags: protractor

How do we handle "&" and " 's " " space" to find elements?
These elements can't be found.

Examples:

```
element(by.xpath("//hs-details-item[hs-label='Jack Daniel's 50ml']//hs-spin/span[2]")).click();

element(by.xpath("//hs-details-item[hs-label='M&M's']//hs-spin/span[2]")).click();

element(by.xpath("//hs-details-item[hs-label='M&Ms Pretzel']//hs-spin/span[2]")).click();
```

Comment: I don't use xpath very much, but are you sure that's correct?  When I locate an element by css, I don't include the quotes in the attribute between the brackets.  For example `element(by.css('form[name=forgotPasswordForm]'))`

Comment: @ Gunderson, I could not find my element using by.css so I had to use by.xpath. For the above examples my elements are not found because of the &, 's characters. if I remove those characters my test fails for not finding the element. I could not write MM instead of M&M.                                       Following is the snippet for M&M's  :                                                  <hs-details-item ng-repeat="item in amenities" style="overflow:hidden" class="ng-scope">
            <hs-label class="ng-binding">M&M's</hs-label>
            <hs-value-block>
                <hs>